# ¿Por qué es malo "ser un pájaro"?

Tags: modismos, etimología

Cuando alguien es bastante pícaro, se usa la frase "ser un pájaro":

> Cuidado con el frutero, siempre intenta colarte fruta demasiado
>   madura. ¡Es un pájaro!

La RAE da como segunda acepción de pájaro:

> [**pájaro, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?w=p%C3%A1jaro&o=h)
>
> Del lat. vulg. passar 'pájaro', y este del lat. passer, -ĕris
>   'gorrión'.
>
> 2. m. y f. Persona astuta y con muy pocos escrúpulos. U. t. c. adj.

Sin embargo, ¿por qué "pájaro" tiene tal mala connotación?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> PAXARO. Metaphoricamente se toma por astúto, sagaz y cauteloso, con alusión al gorrión, que se juzga el más astúto de las aves. Latín. Sagax. Callidus. *—RAE, [Diccionario de autoridades, tomo V (1737)](http://web.frl.es/dtSearch/dtisapi6.dll?cmd=getdoc&DocId=60065&Index=C%3A%5Cinetpub%5Cwwwroot%5CDA%5FINDEX&HitCount=1&hits=1%20&SearchForm=%2FDA%5Fform%2Ehtml)*

Si bien la astucia, la sagacidad y la cautela no son de por sí cualidades negativas; sí que son cualidades necesarias para ser un pícaro y salir airoso. Con sentido negativo ya se recoge como mínimo en el siglo XIX:

> Hombre de cuenta ó pájaro de cuenta:  El reo de gran cuidado o a algún facineroso terrible. *—Roque Barcia, 1880*

PD: Debo confesar, puesto que no soy un pájaro, que todo este trabajo de documentación lo ha hecho un escritor llamado Arturo Ortega Morán, y yo me he limitado a coger los extractos relevantes de [la entrada correspondiente de su blog](https://capsuladelengua.wordpress.com/2008/09/28/pajaro-de-cuenta/), que recomiendo visitar para saber qué significa «de cuenta».

Comment: Fantástica explicación (y postdata :D) Nótese que la etimología de "pájaro" indica que viene de "gorrión" (_Del lat. vulg. passar 'pájaro', y este del lat. passer, -ĕris 'gorrión'_), ergo puede que en algún momento _eres un pájaro_ fuera prácticamente equivalente a _eres un gorrión_.